# Switch values if condition MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to switch the values if a condition is added to the sql query but i don't know exactly how work the if else statement in sql.

This is my query:

DATABASE:

```
attr_id
st_id
prod_id
value
```

Data:

```
$attr_id1   = "75";
$attr_id2   = "76";
$st_id      = array('2','2','2','2');
$prod_id    = array('2','3','4');
$value  = array('150','200','300');
```

SQL:

```
"INSERT INTO table
    (attr_id, st_id, prod_id, value)
    VALUES (IF(value from $attr_id2 is < less  that $value switch to $attr_id2 else to $attr_id1), ".$st_id.", ".$prod_id.", ".$value.")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    value = (".$value.")";
    "WHERE attr_id = ".$attr_id1." //OR ATTR_ID2
    AND st_id = ".$st_id."
    AND prod_id = ".$prod_id."
"
```

DATATABLE:

```
attr_id   st_id  prod_id    value
75          2       2       150
76          2       2       200
75          2       3       300
76          2       3       290
76          2       4       200
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: not clear what you want

Comment: Yes, i think i have not explained very well. What i want is to switch column attr_id1 with attr_id2 if value from attr_id2 is less than attr_id1

Comment: @Dario your column is `attr_id` so want to switch value for this column right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE`

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (attr_id, st_id, prod_id, VALUE) 
VALUES
  (
    CASE
      WHEN ".$attr_id2." < ".$attr_id1."
      THEN ".$attr_id2." 
      ELSE ".$attr_id1." 
    END,
    ".$st_id.",
    ".$prod_id.",
    ".$value."
  ) .....
```

Comment: in case need to be When `value` from `attr_id2` is les than `attr_id1` in this case will be all the time `attr_id2` because 75 is less than 76

Comment: @Dario yes,i guess this is what you said in your comments

Comment: `attr_id` contain value 75 and 76, 75 is price and 76 is special_price, so what i want is to change the value from 75 or 76 when the value from 75 is less than 76, i have updated my question for more understand.

Comment: @Dario sorry unable to understand what you said  can you explain it with some more brief